# npm run build fails with "Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, continuous-integration

I'm seeing an error with npm when I try to build a VueJS application. I'm seeing this error inside of a `build` stage in GitLab CI. I haven't been able to find any mention of the error message. I have previously been able to run `npm run build` successfully and I haven't made any changes to the Vue application code, so I'm unsure what could be causing this error.

```
-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean
Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean
    at Ajv.addKeyword (/app/node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js:65:13)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/ajv-errors/index.js:10:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! code@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the code@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-09T22_32_54_384Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here is what I have in my docker file that is used to build the Vue app:

```
# build stage
FROM node:10.14.2-jessie as build-stage
WORKDIR /app/
COPY frontend/package.json /app/
RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm install
COPY frontend /app/
RUN npm run build
```

Comment: Got the exact same error on a freshly install vue app. Mine was on `npm run serve`.

Comment: A look at the repo for the package shows the file reported by npm was updated an hour ago. Did you by any chance just update the npm dependencies?

Comment: The issue has been raised on the repo. Multiple dependent packages are hit.

Comment: thanks @d00dle, I just saw the issue you mentioned in the `[ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/941#issuecomment-462087356)` package. There seem to be some temporary workarounds in that thread, I'm trying some of them now

Comment: It's a simple work around for now but it worked for me. I set "ajv": "6.8.1" -> https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions

Comment: This has been fixed. Update NPM and it should work again...

Comment: Still getting this issue on 6.9.0 after npm update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768

#### If you use yarn

add below to package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "ajv": "6.8.1"
  }
```

then run `yarn install`

#### if you use npm

```
npm uninstall ajv
npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the node-modules I renamed ajv folder to ajv1. Now I copied an older version of ajv folder into node-modules folder from some other installation. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

***Quick fix:***

Go to the *ajv* dependency in your node_modules folder:

> node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js

comment out the line 64 and 65 :

```
if (!validateDefinition(definition))
  throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));
```

and it should works without side effects.